# What is default password for Android Emulator for Expo?

Tags: android

I am stuck at the stupid password screen for android emulator.

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
}
```

Above password does not work.